# How to use VALUE @expression clause in DEFINE FIELD

Tags: surrealdb

What is the purpose of the `VALUE @expression` clause in a `DEFINE FIELD <field> ON <table>` statement?

I expect it to return the result of the `@expression` if the `<field>` is queried on `<table>`. However, it always returns null, regardless of the `@expression` configured.

Here is an example:

```sql
DEFINE TABLE test SCHEMAFUL;
DEFINE FIELD time ON test VALUE time::now();

CREATE test:some;

SELECT time FROM test:some; # This is where I expect to get the current time
```

The result however dislays a null value.

In the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
```

the `time` field does not even show up.

Comment: can't reproduce this on `surreal 1.0.0-beta.8+20220930.c246533 for linux on x86_64`. It seems to work just fine, although it does only set the time at creation of the row. So it does not show the current time when querying, but the time when the row was inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I will do further testing to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

So the `@expression` part is evaluated upon creating a new record on `<table>` and stored in the `<field>` on that table.

In the given example, a `SELECT * FROM test` would display the creation time of `test:some`. The field being empty cannot be reproduced.